# Adding Drivers To ShredOS

Tags: linux, drivers

I'm wondering if anyone would know how to add some drivers into a live linux distro?

I want to use https://github.com/PartialVolume/shredos.2020.02 but I need some drivers added and I have no idea how to do it.

The drivers I need added are here: https://www.supermicro.com/wftp/driver/SAS/Marvell/MV8/SAS2/Driver/Linux/

Please forgive my total lack of knowledge, I am a developer and a Windows engineer - I get a touch lost with Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the ShredOS but the full installation steps descriped in the Redme.txt, here is the must important steps to load the drivers (from Readme):

```
Insert DUD floppy diskette  into a floppy drive,type in the commands: 
1) login as root 

2) mount /dev/fd0 /media (Legacy Floppy)
or
2) mount /dev/sd<x> /media (USB Floppy)
or
2) mount -o loop centos52.img /media (driver image)

3) cd /media ; sh ./install 

4) cd ~; umount /media
```

Comment: I shall give it a go - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you still looking for a solution to this?

1. Download ShredOS and read up on buildroot. Probably not what you are looking for if you want a quick fix as it's a steep learning curve.
2. Ask @partialvolume(that's me) if he will add that driver on the next update?